# When I have to write in the subjunctive mood?

Tags: verbs, subjunctives

"It has been suggested that the company invest in new machinery".

"It is essential that every child have educational opportunities".

If I want to write something like the above sentences, how could I know that now I have to write my verbs in the subjunctive mood ? Why we use the subjunctive mood in AmE?

If someone also shows how to make thses sentences rewritten using "Should" as it is used in BrE that will be great.

Thank you.

Comment: You should add whether you use AmE or BrE, because  AmE uses present subjunctive in cases where BrE uses a simpler "should".

Comment: @rogermue - I modified my post a little. hope it is ok.  thank you for your advice.